# Regex for everything but "M", "F", "M/F"

Tags: regex

I need a regex to use in Java to replace a String with "UNKNOWN" if the entire String is not "M", "F", or "M/F".  In other words:

- String "M" stays "M"
- String "F" stays "F"
- String "M/F" stays "M/F"
- Anything else becomes "UNKNOWN"

One odd case is "M/" or "F/" which should become "UNKNOWN".  Please help, I'm dying over here.

I'm actually passing the regex into a framework via an xml mapping file, so I don't have programmatic control over how the output is formed. I can only pass in a regex, and what it gets replaced with.

Comment: Why would you want to use a regex for this, instead of regular string comparisons and conditionally a string assignment?

Comment: Does this need to be a regex? You only have three strings to check for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use negative lookahead like this:

```
Pattern.compile("^(?!^(?:M|F|M/F)$).*$");
```

Using String#replaceAll you can do:

```
String replaced = str.replaceAll("^(?!^(?:M|F|M/F)$).*$", "UNKNOWN");
```

Comment: Indeed.  And just replace matches to this with UNKNOWN.

Comment: That did it.  I didn't know about negative lookahead (or regular lookahead for that matter).  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: You're welcome. This is very useful to read about lookarounds in regex: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 0):

You could test whether the string matches `^(M|F|M/F)$` and replace it if it doesn’t match. In pseudocode (because I don’t remember how to do regex in Java):

```
s = "M"
if not match(s, '^(M|F|M/F)$')
    s = "UNKNOWN"
```

Comment: My problem there is that I'm actually passing the regex into a framework via an xml mapping file, so I don't have programmatic control over how the output is formed.  I can only pass in a regex, and what it gets replaced with.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!Pattern.matches("^M$|^F$|^M/F$", string)) {
    string = "UNKNOWN";
}
```

Oh, this is the same answer as Lawrence's.. I'd go for the single cases, though.. aaand I see that it's not what you want.. sorry :)